# AngularJS Ternary Expression not valid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ternary-operator

```
{{var.a != "N/A" ? "<a ng-href='myapp://find?name="+var.a+"'>"+'var.a'+"</a>" :var.a}}
```

My ternary operator in this format for angularjs seems not working (in the view, ternary result is not showing but the exact written code above show in the view). I wonder where is the mistake as no error is returned on anywhere in chrome inspector.

I use Angularjs 1.2.2

Even way to troubleshoot it will really help.

Thank you

Comment: What are all the `.` doing? Are you trying to concatenate those strings and variables (like in PHP)? If so, use `+` in JavaScript

Comment: @Ian Did that, but still the same...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use:

```
<a ng-href="myapp://find?name={{var.var1}}" ng-show="var.var1 != 'N/A'">{{var.var1}}</a>
<span ng-hide="var.var1 != 'N/A'">{{var.var1}}</span>
```

You can also use [ng-switch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch).